# How can I retrieve instance of children component

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I need access the instance of children component:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <CustomForm />
    </Provider>
);
```

I need to access `CustomForm` instance .. how can I do this?

I tried:

```
const instance = wrapper
    .children(0)
    .instance();
```

Comment: You could probably get to it with [.dive()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test needs to access the instances of child components then you will need to use `mount()` instead of `shallow()`.

[`shallow()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) does not do a full DOM rendering and creates an instance for the root element if it is declared using a class (note that [functional components never have instances](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#summary)), but it does not create instances for child components.

[`mount()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) does a full DOM rendering and creates instances for all components (root or child) declared using classes.

In your example you are using `chilren(0)` to access the `ReactWrapper`, alternatives are `childAt(0)`, or something like `find('Component').at(0)`.

Here is a simple working example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

class Component extends React.Component {
  componentMethod = () => 'componentMethod called'

  render() { 
    return (
      <span>The Component</span>
    );
  }
}

test('get component instance', () => {
  const component = mount(
    <div>
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
  const componentInstance = component.find('Component').at(0).instance();
  expect(componentInstance.componentMethod()).toBe('componentMethod called'); // PASSES
});
```